# Initializing to null at declaration vs using conditional

Tags: c#

I'm aware that premature optimization is the root of all evil but I'm going to ask this anyway.

Say I have this:

```
string foo = null;
if (IsBar) {
    foo = "...";
    // something else
}
```

But I think I read somewhere long time ago that giving a value to a variable will be slightly slower. Hence, I am contemplating on doing this:

```
string foo;
if (!IsBar) {
    foo = null;
} else {
    foo = "...";
    // something else
}
```

May I ask which is the best practice?

Comment: `giving a value to a variable will be slightly slower.` no it won't. `null` is the default value of `foo` so assigning null to it serves no purpose.

Comment: Even if it would matter you are wasting your time for micro optimisations. Try to use profilers like [CodeTrack](https://www.getcodetrack.com/) to understand where is your performance bottleneck and then decide whether or not does it make sense to spend your efforts to optimize that part.

Comment: `string foo = null;` is the same as `string foo;`. and in terms of code quality it would be plain wrong if you write `string foo = "a"; foo = "b";`

Comment: Optimize for *readability* first. Write the one you prefer to read afterwards.

Comment: Best practice: prefer Readability over performance, unless you're actually having a performance problem. When you have a performance problem, make sure you find the problem by using benchmark tools, and optimize where the bottle neck actually exists.

This will not be a bottle neck, even if assigning `null` was "slightly slower".

Comment: If `foo` doesn't need a value... why give it one?

Comment: @Andrew presumably because in the lines following the code shown, you would get "Unassigned use of local variable" if you didn't assign `null` to it.

Comment: @Llama which is where a meaningful default would come in. Whichever way you go about it - if your default is null, then you're just going to need a null check further on

Comment: @Andrew I see what you mean. I was approaching it from the perspective of `null` being meaningful in and of itself in this scenario. I accept that that is perhaps not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has really nothing to do with performance, but there's a difference anyway.

If you assign a value you lose the capability that VS or resharper help you to determine if the variable gets intialized in one of the branches, that could help you to find a logical bug in your code. So that might be a disadvantage. But as you can see in your sample it's getting a little bit more verbose if you don't assign `null`.

It depends on the actual case if you should prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

string foo = IsBar ? "..." : null;